# Weird output of ZFS list regarding filesystem sizes

Tags: zfs

I created some zfs datasets using the following options:

```
zfs create ...

data/media -o reserv=1TB
data/audiostudio -o reserv=600GB
data/database -o reserv=20GB
data/Git-Backup -o reserv=20GB
data/PC-Backup-Linux -o reserv=300GB
data/PC-Backup-Windows -o reserv=300GB
data/docker-images -o reserv=100GB
data/logs -o reserv=20GB
```

However, the output of `zfs list` is like

```
NAME                     USED  AVAIL     REFER  MOUNTPOINT
data                    2.33T  1.18T      352K  /data
data/Git-Backup          192K  1.20T      192K  /data/Git-Backup
data/PC-Backup-Linux     192K  1.48T      192K  /data/PC-Backup-Linux
data/PC-Backup-Windows   192K  1.48T      192K  /data/PC-Backup-Windows
data/audiostudio         192K  1.77T      192K  /data/audiostudio
data/database            192K  1.20T      192K  /data/database
data/docker-images       192K  1.28T      192K  /data/docker-images
data/logs                192K  1.20T      192K  /data/logs
data/media               192K  2.18T      192K  /data/media
```

How does it calculate the available space? I would have expected around approx 4TB for all of them (total pool size, all datasets still empty).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We see the total space is `2.33TB + 1.18TB = 3.48TB`.

The reservation concept considered as `USED` in `zfs list` output. Because by reserving, ZFS guarantees that a specified amount of disk space is available to a file system, so the reserved amount considered as used from `/data` (it's no more available for other filesystems so it is like already used space)

So here `USED` space of `/data` is sum of the reserved amounts.

`2.33T = 1TB + 600GB + 20GB + 20GB + 300GB + 300GB + 100GB + 20GB`

`1.18GB` is `AVAIL` from `/data` which means any dataset that exceeds the reserved amount can use it, so for example `/data/media` has `1.18TB AVAIL + 1TB RESERVED = 2.18TB available for this dataset`

For `/data/logs` is `1.18TB + 20GB = 1.20TB` and...

We cannot expect `3.48TB` available for each dataset, because by reservation each dataset has already owned the reserved amount from `/data` and only **unreserved** space is available for all datasets.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification :) makes sense :)

Comment: Is there a way to see how much space is actually used, or how much space is reserved but not used?